# Java App Using CP-SAT works on Windows, but not macOS

Tags: java, or-tools, unsatisfiedlinkerror, cp-sat

I am working on an application which integrates the CP-SAT functionality from Google OR-Tools. It runs perfectly on my Windows machine, but running the exact same code in IntelliJ on my MacBook leads to this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Can't load library: /var/folders/fh/p53vbgc50gq9h80kn950pvnh0000gn/T/ortools-java17235137568310781234/darwin/libjniortools.dylib
```

I am a beginner, so I don't understand what this means, and cannot find any solution.

I tried changing the library importing code from `OrToolsHelper.loadLibrary();` to `Loader.loadNativeLibraries();`. This helps. The code gets further along, but it still shows another Unsatisfied Link Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
byte[] com.google.ortools.sat.mainJNI.SatHelper_solveWithParameters(byte[], byte[])
```

Comment: version ? platform ? java version ? Are they the same on mac and on windows?

Comment: Note that `OrToolsHelper.loadLibrary();` has never been document, or used in any distributed examples, and thus should not be used.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, thank you for letting me know. I will update my program accordingly. Do you have any solution to the problem I'm facing after implementing `Loader.loadNativeLibraries()`? I have the same version of Java on both the Windows and macOS machines - 19.0.2. Please let me know any other information you need - this is my first time posting on Stackoverflow. The code being run is identical on both machines.

Comment: jna version ? or-tools version ? is it a arm64 mac or an intel one ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron - OR-Tools version 9.7.2996 on an M1 Pro chip. I'm sorry but I don't know how to check the JNA version.

Comment: this is a java library. Make sure it is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3930) on the OR-Tools github.

Most likely the issue is that you need to force the jna dependency in the maven configuration file to use the latest version.